# Задание стилей через javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Я новичек в web программировании и хотел бы уточнить.

Например:

У нас есть обычный блок растянутый на 100%, а в нем картинка (картинка абсолютно спозицианирована)

Нужно картинку выровнить по середине.

Нужно картинку выровнить по центру.

Я это делаю так:

в js

window.onload = function () {
и тут я выщитываю ккординаты для картинки, и присваеваю ему.
}

Можно ли таким образом вышитывать координаты или размеры других блоков и элементов? С точки зрения реализации это правильно? Будет ли всегда хорошо работать?

Answer (score 1):

Незачем использовать JS, это должно делаться на CSS:

- за примером можно сюда: http://jsfiddle.net/aaNuQ/

Если принципиально абсолютное позиционирование, то два варианта:

- знаете ширину и высоту картинки http://jsfiddle.net/ULTjt/ (предпочтительнее)
- НЕ знаете ширину и высоту http://jsfiddle.net/E7xpb/

PS: во втором примере можно поиграться с margin, и попробовать такие значения:

```
margin: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
margin: auto 0;
margin: auto;
```